# How to adjust p-values in a multiple regression when variables have been a selected by Lasso?

Tags: inference, feature-selection, multiple-comparisons, lasso

I have designed an analysis where I am testing a lot of variables together. So I first apply a Lasso regression to select the top variables, and then I run a standard (unregularized) multiple regression with only the selected variables. Which p-values should I report?

I was initially reporting the multiple regression p-values (that each coefficient is non-zero), but I discovered that this might be a case of "post-selection inference"[1], so that these p-values should actually be adjusted.

What type of correction would you apply? I applied Benjamini-Hochberg on the p-values of the selected variables, which are typically less than 10 in number. It does not look stringent enough, as it barely changes the number of significant variables. Should I take into account all the initial variables (but I don't have p-values with the Lasso)?

EDIT: The reason I automatically select variables is that there is a lot of collinearity. For some of them, I know in advance about their correlation, but I don't know which one would have the strongest correlation with my response variable.

[1]: Kuchibhotla et al. 2022, Post-selection inference (https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-statistics-100421-044639)

Comment: Good question, but *very* hard to answer. Benjamini-Hochberg is not the right tool, and any solution will likely be much more stringent.

Comment: Why don't you have p values with the Lasso?

Comment: @PeterFlom Initially, Lasso was not designed with p-values. I think there are ways to compute them but it's not straightforward and it is not implemented in the Statsmodel Python package.

Comment: OK.  I know that one idea was to use JUST the model from Lasso, do a regression on that model and use that to get p values and model diagnoistics and stuff.  I think there was a SAS paper by Bob Rodriguez on this, but I'm not positive (it was a long time ago).

Answer (score 6):

The approach you're describing (first LASSO then re-apply an unpenalized model) goes by the name "Relaxo" or "Relaxed Lasso" (see [here](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/relax.html)).

While LASSO has post selection inference methods, I think getting valid inference for Relaxo would be much harder.

Can you tell us why you need to select variables?  Why not just use your domain expertise to determine what to adjust for?  Why not just use post selection inference?

Comment: I select variables because otherwise the multiple regression coefficients are unstable due to collinearity (I edited my question). What do you mean with "use post selection inference". This is new to me and I don't know how to do that properly.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Post selection inference is a group of methods for doing hypothesis testing with LASSO. Typically this is infeasible because the (intentional) bias in the LASSO means the coefficients of that model no longer have the required sampling distribution for typical inference we might do from linear regression.

Is your goal prediction (i.e. you want to predict new observations) or inference (i.e. estimating the effects of some variable on the outcome)

Comment: Thanks. I am primarily interested in infering which variables have an effect on the response.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong  If you're interested in inference, I would either skip the daa driven model selection, or perform PCA on highly correlated variable groupings and infer the effect of the first PCA.  Collinearity typically just increases the width of the confidence interval, but if you're concerned about that then I think there are lots of other things you could do that begin with better design.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, relaxed lasso as originally proposed by Meinshausen (2007) amounts to fitting a penalized model in both steps, unlike you indicate. Meanwhile, something like what you describe was called LARS-OLS in Meinshausen (2007). You may wish to edit for precision.

Comment: _Relaxed lasso_ has many problems including the predictions being potentially horribly miscalibrated.  In general the idea of using _lasso_ to select variables (and _elastic net_ would have been better) and then inserting that variable subset into a standard analysis violates many statistical principles.  In a linear model you’d see a terrible downward bias in $\hat{\sigma}$.